# CSS: Padding wrong with video embeds

Tags: css

i have an issue with the theme i am developing for my blog ([example](http://jiewmeng.tumblr.com/post/642917176/quick-tip-the-multi-column-css3-module-via)), where below a video, there is a "extra" space/padding to its border

[image]

basically, i have a

```
<div class="media"> ... embeded stuff ... </div>

.media { border: 5px solid #CCC }
```

something like that

Comment: Have you tried using Firebug to determine which element has the extra padding? Once you know where it is, you should be able to remove it in your stylesheet.

Comment: What VoteyDisciple says, plus can you show the HTML of the embedded Video?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add this to your css:

```
object{
  vertical-align:bottom;
}
```

(or, alternatively, set `line-hight` to 0 for your .media)

Answer (score 3):

Set `line-height` to 0 for the `.media` rule because the whitespace takes up space ( *white* :p ) ..

```
.media { border: 5px solid #CCC;line-height:0; }
```